# Integral of trig functions (problem below)

Tags: integration

[image]

I'm trying to understand the work that they did. I understand that they split the fraction up, but I do not understand the substitution they did for each fraction, especially the x = tant. Does the second fraction show a trig identity?

Comment: $u=x^2+1$ and $x=\tan t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1+\tan^2\clubsuit=1+\dfrac{\sin^2\clubsuit}{\cos^2\clubsuit}=\dfrac{\cos^2\clubsuit}{\cos^2\clubsuit}+\dfrac{\sin^2\clubsuit}{\cos^2\clubsuit}=\dfrac{\cos^2\clubsuit+\sin^2\clubsuit}{\cos^2\clubsuit}=\dfrac1{\cos^2\clubsuit}=\sec^2\clubsuit$

Comment: Yes but how does this relate to substituting in 1/sqrt(x^2+1)?

Comment: Read it with $t$ instead of $x$ and use $x=\tan t$.

Comment: @ilovedanielkimisaweaboo: Better now ? :-|